# Evince does not open hyperlinks after updating ubuntu 18.04

Tags: evince

I ran the software updater today for Ubuntu 18.04.  Now evince does not open links in the viewed pdf anymore in my browser (chrome) but gives this error message in the terminal:

> [24120:24120:0726/114731.031048:FATAL:double_fork_and_exec.cc(131)] execv /opt/google/chrome/crashpad_handler: Permission denied (13)

Help please?  Please?

Comment: I found the answer belatedly at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357638