# Evince can not open links in snap Firefox

Tags: firefox, snap, pdf, evince, apparmor

When I click on a link in a PDF document in Evince, it does not work. Instead, I only see cursor turning into a spinner and a message appearing in the terminal:

```
env: ‘/snap/bin/firefox’: Permission denied
```

The closest thing I have found is the following bug report for evince itself https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1090

which suggests that the problem is in the AppArmor profiles that do not allow Evince to run programs in the home directory.

How can I solve this?

I use Ubuntu 21.10 with Firefox installed from Snaps

**Update Nov 2023** The bug have been fixed in Ubuntu 23.10. For bug discussion see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1794064

Comment: Is this problem due to Evince being a snap or Firefox being a snap? I think in your case, it is the second.

Comment: @FedKad Firefox is a snap, Evince is deb from Ubuntu repositories

Comment: Then, remove the snap version of Firefox and install the "apt" (deb) version. You may need to save and reuse the "profile folder" of Firefox though!

Comment: @FedKad that is just a workaround that will not be applicable anymore for the next Ubuntu release.

Comment: Can you provide detail on the type of link? Is this a www URL, or a link to a local file?

Comment: This is a web URL link.

Comment: I reported a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1968552 - you may want to click "affects me too".

Comment: Same issue by the way with the Chromium snap if you make it the default browser:
env: ‘/snap/bin/chromium’: Permission denied

Answer (score 4):

This `env: ‘/snap/bin/firefox’: Permission denied` or `env: ‘/snap/bin/chromium’: Permission denied` issue in `evince` launched through a terminal can be traced back to `apparmor`. Doing `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep -i apparmor` (from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357638/permission-denied-when-evince-tries-to-use-chrome-to-open-link#comment2324835_1357638)), you may find a line where the following appears `apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" name="/usr/bin/snap" profile="/usr/bin/evince" comm="env"`.

This can maybe be fixed by tuning the `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince` profile, or by a modification of the abstractions like `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-helpers` or `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-browsers` (e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357638/permission-denied-when-evince-tries-to-use-chrome-to-open-link/1357841#1357841) or [there](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/964510)).

A radical change which worked for me but may lead to security issues is to just disable `apparmor` for `evince` with `sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince /etc/apparmor.d/disable/usr.bin.evince`. It it written [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317928/hyperlinks-clicked-in-evince-document-viewer-are-not-opening-any-ideas-on-how-t/693663#693663) that `sudo service apparmor restart` would then engage the changes but a full computer restart was needed in my case.

EDIT: A somewhat less radical move could be to add a `/usr/bin/snap Ux,` line towards the end of the `/usr/bin/evince {...}` block of `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince` (see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/964510#yui_3_10_3_1_1662912001806_169)) and restarting the service with `sudo service apparmor restart`. That may still not be entirely safe, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling Evince from APT and installing it from Snap:

```bash
sudo apt remote evince
sudo snap install evince
```

You may need to log out and in again. You may also need to reconfigure the file type associations.

This was suggested in the [bug report discussion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1794064/comments/2). Apparently, at the moment, you need either Evince and your browser from APT, or both from snap.

Comment: Update: I reverted to Evince from apt, as I then had other issues integrating with the rest of the system.

Comment: Update 2: In case that is an option for you to consider another PDF reader, Okular from APT works just fine.