# After upgrade to 22.04 LTS: Cannot open links from evince

Tags: permissions, updates, firefox, 22.04, evince

After the upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS I observed that I can no longer open weblinks from evince. I get the following error message on the terminal where I called evince:

```
sh: 1: exec: kfmclient: Permission denied
```

How to fix this?

P.S. After reading this question and its answers [permission denied when Evince tries to use Chrome to open link](https://askubuntu.com/q/1357638/284224) I looked up /var/log/syslog and found this entry there:

```
Nov 30 17:46:01 uds1045586 kernel: [ 3559.812587] audit: type=1400 audit(1669826761.259:175): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/usr/bin/kfmclient" pid=7788 comm="sh" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=1001 ouid=0
```

EDIT: My browser is firefox (it was the default browser before the upgrade) and it is now a snap.

Comment: works fine for me from 22.04.1 loading a link from a URL in evince 42.3

Comment: @24601: When it works for you: Did you do anything with apparmor (configuration, switch it off)? Or do you use an installation "out of the box"?

Comment: vanilla, straight out of the box